# How to allign a MS Word table to center Using delphi XE 5

Tags: delphi, ms-word, delphi-xe5

I know how to allign the text inside a table's cells.

But i cannot figure out how to allign the entire table center

I use the following code to create the table and to set its borders.

```
wrdDoc.Tables.Add(wrdSelection.Range,1,1);
wrdDoc.Tables.Item(1).Columns.Item(1).SetWidth(462,wdAdjustNone);
wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle := wdLineStyleDouble;
wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderRight).LineStyle := wdLineStyleDouble;
wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle := wdLineStyleNone;
wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderTop).LineStyle := wdLineStyleDouble;
wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle := wdLineStyleDouble;
wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle := wdLineStyleNone;
```

How can i set the table properties to allign center?

Note: i did find the page below which was supposed to have the sample code on microsoft's site, but it has nothing of worth.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834583(v=office.14).aspx

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally get an answer on http://www.delphigroups.info/2/da/258008.html

the code needed was `wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Rows.Alignment := wdAlignRowCenter;`

But thanks anyway guys.